# Meaning of this sentence with would

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence, modal-verbs

My friend said **I did not think I would marry her**. Why did he use **would** in that sentence?

Comment: How on earth are we to know what your friend was thinking? We assume he used would because he was speaking in English.

Answer (score 1):

Your clause-  *I would marry her* is sometimes referred to as Future in the Past.

We use it to express the idea that in the past you thought something would happen in the future. It does not matter if you are correct or not. Future in the past follows the same basic rules as the simple future. "Would" is used to volunteer or promise, and "was going to" is used to plan. Moreover, both forms can be used to make predictions about the future.

You can find more examples and information here:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future/future-in-the-past

Answer (score 0):

From Wiktionary:

> 6. Was determined to; loosely, could naturally have been expected to (given the tendencies of someone's character etc.).

*"I did not think I would marry her"* is equivalent to *"I was not aware I wanted to marry her"*; "Would" implies that at the time before their marriage, they were not aware they wanted to marry.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd read "I did not think I would marry her" as "I was not aware I wanted to marry her", I'd say it was closer to "I did not expect to marry her".